# Как переместить предмет ссылки вверх по оси Y, html

Tags: python, html, django, html5

Начал изучать Django, html и css, и уже столкнулся с проблемой: нужно переместить элементы ссылок на темный фон, на уровень с логотипом, попробовал с помощью всяких элементов позиционирования, но чет не вышло.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
    background: #c2c2c2;
}

aside {
    float: inline-start;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    padding: 2.5%;
    height: 10vh;
    /* color: #fff; */
}

aside img {
    height: 10vh;
    width: 33vh;
    margin-top: -4.8vh;
    margin-left: -9vh;
}

aside ul {
    list-style: none;
}

aside ul li {

    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: -10vh;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
} 

aside ul li:hover, aside ul a:hover {
    color: #7284e2;
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/css/main.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <aside>
        <img src="{% static 'main/img/logo2.png' %}" alt="Лого">
        <span class="logo"></span>
        <ul>
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="button"><li>Главная</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'order' %}" class="button"><li>Заказать</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'contacts' %}" class="button"><li>Контакты</li></a>
        </ul>
        <style>
            a {
            text-decoration: none;
            }
          </style>
    </aside>
    <main>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример, но я вам нужно подучить html, так как вы формируете разметку не пойдёт.

```css
body {
    background: #c2c2c2;
}

aside {
    background: #2c2c2c;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

aside .logo {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: white;
}

aside ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 50px;
}

aside ul li {

    display: block;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
} 

aside ul li:hover, aside ul a:hover {
    color: #7284e2;
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <aside>
        <div class="logo"><span class="img">Логотип</span></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="button">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="button">Заказать</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="button">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
        <style>
            a {
            text-decoration: none;
            }
          </style>
    </aside>
    <main>
        <p>КОнтент</p>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Также не ставьте высоту оборачивающему тегу, в данном случае вы задали его aside, внутренние объекты должны растягивать содержащий их контейнер, то есть если Логотип поменяется и его высота станет выше, он перестанет помещаться в aside, так как вы задали ему конкретную высоту. Потом сначала идёт ul -> li -> a и только в таком порядке. Не используйте параметры vh и vw пока изучаете css, только px и %.